# GitHub Pages and Jekyll MacOS

Tags: macos, github, terminal, jekyll, github-pages

I am creating a GitHub website via Jekyll on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7.

When I run the command `bundle exec jekyll serve` it results in an error.

My project is here: https://github.com/dbarnes18/dbarnes18 and my error is here:

```
dillonbarnes@Downstairs-iMac gh-pages % bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages
       Destination: /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.282 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages'
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll)
/Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- webrick (LoadError)
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:184:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:184:in `setup'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:102:in `process'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:494:in `exec'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
dillonbarnes@Downstairs-iMac gh-pages % jekyll b
/Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:302:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated i18n 1.8.10, but your Gemfile requires i18n 0.9.5. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:163:in `each'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:163:in `each'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `map'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `setup'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `setup'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:52:in `require_from_bundler'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
dillonbarnes@Downstairs-iMac gh-pages % bundle exec jekyll build
Configuration file: /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/_config.yml
^[[A            Source: /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages
       Destination: /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.271 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
dillonbarnes@Downstairs-iMac gh-pages % bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages
       Destination: /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.232 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages'
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll)
/Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- webrick (LoadError)
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:184:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:184:in `setup'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:102:in `process'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/GitHub/dbarnes18/gh-pages/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:494:in `exec'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /Users/dillonbarnes/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
dillonbarnes@Downstairs-iMac gh-pages %
```

Please can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

I should add that I do NOT have admin/sudo privileges on my Mac.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please try to post the relevant content/error here so we don't have to go down links.

Comment: I have put the log in the message and removed the GitHub Gist link.

Comment: See this link https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523. Either you need to add ```gem webrick``` to a new ```Gemfile``` in your folder or ```bundle add webrick```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523.
Either you need to add `gem webrick` to a new Gemfile in your folder or `bundle add webrick.`

This will then give `jekyll` access to the packages it needs.

Comment: Add the answer description in your answer, actually, your post is not an answer, it is a comment. At that moment you should gather reputation to reach 50 and be able to write comments, but now your reps are more than 50, edit your answer to be of better quality.

Comment: Another thing. do not mention any person in our answer, especially for saying acknowledgments. it is an answer and should guide other users of the community. If you wanna say thanks, you should use comments instead.